# Edit - __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create "Edit" for my form.

urls.py

```
url(r'^app_1/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/edit/$',views.edit, name = 'edit'),
```

forms.py

```
class ClanakForma(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Clanak
    fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Clanak(models.Model):
    naslov = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=120)
    datumObjave = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    autor = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.naslov) + ', ' + str(self.datumObjave) + ', ' + str(self.autor)
```

views.py

```
def edit(request, id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Clanak, id = id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ClanakForma(request.Clanak, instance=data)
        if form.is_vaild():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.naslov = request.user
            data.datumObjave = request.user
            data.autor = request.user
            data.email = request.user
            return redirect('readAllNew')
    else:
        form = ClanakForma(instance=data)
        template = 'readAllNew.html'
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

readAllNew.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">

        <tr>
        <th>Naslov</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Autor</th>
        <th>Mail</th>
        </tr>
        {% for x in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.naslov}}</td>
        <td>{{x.datumObjave}}</td>
        <td>{{x.autor}}</td>
        <td>{{x.email}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'delete' x.id %}">delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'edit' x.id %}">edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I hit edit link at my "readAllNew.html" I get error:

> TypeError at /app_1/5/edit/
>   **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

I think something is wrong with my view but I am not sure what.

-------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------

As suggested I edited "forms.py" but now I am not seeing any form field so I can't edit nothing:

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNYH7.png)

---------------- UPDATE 2 -------------------------

I created new html file as "edit.html"

I edited "views.py":

```
def edit(request, id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Clanak, id = id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ClanakForma(instance=data)
        if form.is_vaild():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.naslov = request.user
            data.datumObjave = request.user
            data.autor = request.user
            data.email = request.user
            return redirect('readAllNew.html')
    else:
        form = ClanakForma(instance=data)
        template = 'edit.html'
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

Now I see fields and informations in it properly, but when I change something and click on "SUBMIT" I get error:

```
AttributeError at /app_1/6/edit/
'ClanakForma' object has no attribute 'is_vaild'
```

Comment: Can you add complete `readAllNew.html` file?

Comment: @JPG I added complete "readAllNew.html" file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`forms.ModelForm`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) instead of ***`forms.Form`***

```
class Forma(forms.ModelForm):
    naslov = forms.CharField(label='naslov')
    datumObjave = forms.DateField(label='datumObjave')
    autor = forms.CharField(label='autor')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='email')

    class Meta:
        model = Clanak
        fields = ('naslov', 'datumObjave', 'autor', 'email')
```

---

If you want to use ***all the fields of Model class*** in your form, you could specify the **`fields`** attribute of **`Meta`** class as **`fields = '__all__'`**

```
#example
class Forma(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Clanak
        fields = '__all__'
```

If you are using **`forms.ModelForm`**, you could avoid most of the implementation which makes things easier :)

---

#### Update

You need to render the form in your template.So, change your template as

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You, it does work but now I have another problem and I don't know if those two are connected or not so can You please check my update above?

Comment: Which type of form are you using? **`ModelForm`** or **`Form`** class?

Comment: Now I am using ModelForm, maybe it is not reading data correctly and that is why it is blank?

Comment: Thank You, can You check my "Update 2" maybe?

Comment: Oh bro...since you got answer regarding the original post and the updated question is different from the current context. So, you should ask a new question 

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `instance` to simple form - it has to be `ModelForm`. Use this:

```py
class Forma(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Clanak
        fields = ['naslov', 'datumObjave', 'autor', 'email']
        labels = {
            'naslov': 'naslov',
            'datumObjave': 'datumObjave',
            'autor': 'autor',
            'email': 'email'
        }
```